# Positioning of jQuery/Java toggle content

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML-Code:

```
<div class="test-container">
    <div class="slide-button" data-content="panel1">
        <p><span class="panel-icon">+</span>  Test1</p>
    </div>  
    <div id="panel1" style="display: none">
        <p> Test jquery menu1 </p>
    </div>
    <div class="slide-button" data-content="panel2">
        <p><span class="panel-icon">+</span>  Test2</p>
    </div>  
    <div id="panel2" style="display: none">
        <p> Test jquery menu2 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery/Java-Code:

```
$(".slide-button").on('click', function() {
   var panelId = $(this).attr('data-content');
   $('#'+panelId).toggle(500);
   $(this).find('.panel-icon').text(function(_, txt) {
       return txt === "+" ? "-" : "+";
   }); 
});
```

The toggle itself works perfectly. When I click on the slide-button the content will slide-down. However, after the slide-down animation is finished the content somehow "jumps up" to its final position.

How can I avoid this "jump" and get the content stays where it is after the slide-down animation is finished?

Thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your circumstances are, and whether you need `<p>`aragraph tags or not, but if you switch the `<p>` tags inside your "panels" to `<span>` tags it seems to fix your issue.
The HTML code I used which fixed the jump looks like this:

```
<div class="test-container">
<div class="slide-button" data-content="panel1">
    <p><span class="panel-icon">+</span> Test1</p>
</div>
<div id="panel1" style="display: none">

    <!-- Here is the first change from a paragraph to a span tag -->
    <span>Test jquery menu1</span>

</div>
<div class="slide-button" data-content="panel2">
    <p><span class="panel-icon">+</span> Test2</p>
</div>
<div id="panel2" style="display: none">

    <!-- Here is the second change from a paragraph to a span tag -->
    <span>Test jquery menu2</span>

</div>
```

Also, just a friendly tip, Java is not the same as JavaScript. (: Keep that in mind when tagging your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it is working exactly how I want it :-) However, once I add a <p> tag inside the <span> tag the same jumping problem appears. Instead I have to use a <div> tag to avoid the jumping.